# Display a browser compatibility alert via CSS (grid support)

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, browser-support

I can detect browser support and display an "alert" (a styled div) about compatibility for CSS grids with JS:

```
function isUpToDate() {
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.style.display = 'grid'
  return div.style.display === 'grid'
}

if (!isUpToDate) {
  displaySomethingAboutBrowserCompatibility()
}
```

Is there a way in raw CSS to do this kind of thing: drawing a div with CSS rules that makes the div only visible if grid is not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [@supports](https://davidwalsh.name/css-supports) for this.

Display the warning by default, and hide if it the feature you want is supported.

```css
div {
   display: block;
   margin: 1em;
   text-align: center;
   border: solid red 4px;
}

@supports(display: grid) {
    .grids { display: none; }
}

@supports(display: fakedisplay) {
    .fakedisplay { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<div class="grids">Grid is not supported</div>

<div class="fakedisplay">Fake Display is not supported</div>
```

Comment: but is *supports* supported by all browser?

Comment: @TemaniAfif If  `supports` is not supported, then the message is shown and obviously grid is not either  supported ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply use grid properties to style a `div` in order to make it invisble and if grid is not supported it will be visible.

Here is an idea. Open this using an old IE browser to see the result.

```css
.box {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:0px;
  grid-template-rows:0px;
}
.box * {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div>I am a div inside a grid, if you see me than you cannot use grid</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends. You could theoretically use [@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports). ~The only problem with that is that `@supports` doesn't have enough browser support for you to rely on it.~

*edit: @Quentin's answer shows you can do the inverse of this to have supported browsers turn off the message, which is a great solution to my browser support objection.*

If you have a compelling reason not to use JS and don't mind this not working in all versions of IE and older versions of every browser, you could do something like

```
@supports not (text-align: center) {
    .myTextAlignCenterNotSupportedDivMessage {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

But this wouldn't be my approach. It wouldn't be dismissible. You couldn't use LocalStorage to remember their choice. Etc.